# Preferable platform for video-editing and viewing - Executable program / Web-based?

Tags: javascript, python, video, html, html5-video

I need to make a light-weight application for video editing and viewing.

I was thinking of either writing an executable program written in Python, or a light-weight web app using JavaScript and HTML5. Flash, as a third option, is pretty much out of the question, since it's too fat and has many security flaws.

**EDIT:** The video serving itself (read: the "heavy-weight stuff")  will be done by a dedicated fast library or service. Thus, the Python/Web-app questions is pretty much related only to the GUI and some very basic video manipulation, like jumping to a specific frame and such.

What is the preferable platform, considering speed and ease of use (for the user)? Should I just use Python, or maybe just build a small web-app for my task?

Thanks in advace,
Ory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually developed a web-app - HTML5 & CSS. Developing a GUI in HTML is a breeze. And the Chromium (Open-source Google Chrome) handles HTML5  pretty well.

Unlike what people have said here, it is not heavy.

Answer (score 2):

**Python.**

Really, while you can do some fancy tricks with HTML5 Video e.g. apply effects to it and render it on a canvas, rotate the player etc. I don't know of ***any*** encoder that's written in JavaScript.

So unless you want to write your own version of FFMPEG for JavaScript, which will probably be the slowest thing on earth and take 400k lines of code (talk about "lightweight") so I'd suggest that you go with Python.

There are things like [PyFFMPEG](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) or [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/faq.html) out there, which are sure worth a look, but keep in mind Video editing is hard.

Comment: You are right - and I have thought about that, but forgot to mention it in my question. I do not intend to encode the video on JavaScript or Python. I'll use a dedicated tool for it. See me edited question for details.

Comment: And speaking from my experience playing with different techniques for generating audio, trying to feed it to the browser in reasonable-sized chunks with `data:` URLs is about all you can do but it doesn't cut it (can't be done smoothly). You'd need something like the Firefox 4 Audio Data API except for video. And even if you did get it working - in all probability excessive memory usage would render it infeasible. Video is just too big.

Comment: So you're going to just use the thing as GUI, and then send cut etc. command with frame id's to a back end? In that case you still need to load the videos. Chrome supports WebM and h264, Safari only h264, Opera and Firefox both support OGV and WebM. You see format support is a mess right now, also support for getting the data also varies between implementations Firefox currently has the lead on that, but again it doesn't support h264 videos.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use any of those: Browsers can't handle the weight of an application like that, python would take ages to render. If you want to make the frontends in python and/or HTML/JS feel free but you will need a compiled (Preferably C/C++) application to handle the heavy lifting in the background (For HTML, especially if you plan on making it actually have a working preview)

You'd have more luck with flash than with HTML for this...

Comment: Yes yes, I forgot to mention that the heavy video encoding and such will not be in HTML or Python. I'll use a dedicated tool or library for this. See my edited question for more details.

Comment: In that case, either will work (But the HTML version will either need serious server side work or lack of a preview)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think writing a web based video editing system would be a small endeavor.  Flash and Silverlight would be the technologies of choice for something like this.  They are both designed to handle video very well and I think an RIA interface would be ideal.

Sure they may be 'fat' but you got to use the right tool for the job :]

I think [Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/) uses a Flash based system.

You can use Python behind the scenes to do encoding, and connecting video snippets together, but doing the front end with HTML 5 seems masochistic. It is probably possibly to do it with HTML 5 / Canvas, but still pretty crazy!

Comment: Why would writing the front-end GUI in HTML5 & JavaScript be masochistic? It's faster that Flash and you can pretty much do anything that Flash can in HTML5 & JavaScript. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Silverlight will certainly outperform HTML5 & JavaScript since you are getting the local .Net runtime.  Based on the amount of JavaScript you would have to sling and it all being very DOM heavy I'm pretty confident Flash would outperform it as well.    RIA technologies were designed more for writing thick apps for the web.  If you are talking about doing something like a mini iMovie / Movie Maker you'll have more tools and help available doing RIA than HTML5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wish I could voted two different answers as a V (solution).